# How do I fill in every single face correctly?

Tags: faces

I wound up with this hole that I need to close, but I can't seem to find a good way to do it and fill in every single face. Bridge edge loops only work in one axis, so it's not that great. Is there another tool for this?

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Select the 2 opposite edges and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>F</kbd> > *Grid Fill*